# C++ U32 type header

Tags: c++, c

I want to use *U32* type but I can't find the header where it is defined. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no standard type called `U32`, but if you `#include <cstdint>` (`stdint.h` for C) you can use `std::uint32_t`<sup>1</sup>, a 32 bit unsigned integer, which is (I assume) what you want.

Here is [a list of types in the `cstdint` header](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.aix.doc/standlib/header_cstdint.htm):

```
namespace std {
    int8_t
    int16_t
    int32_t
    int64_t
    int_fast8_t
    int_fast16_t
    int_fast32_t
    int_fast64_t
    int_least8_t
    int_least16_t
    int_least32_t
    int_least64_t
    intmax_t
    intptr_t
    uint8_t
    uint16_t
    uint32_t
    uint64_t
    uint_fast8_t
    uint_fast16_t
    uint_fast32_t
    uint_fast64_t
    uint_least8_t
    uint_least16_t
    uint_least32_t
    uint_least64_t
    uintmax_t
    uintptr_t
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Thanks Martinho Fernandes for pointing out that these types are in the namespace `std`.

Comment: On "Game Engine Architecture" there a code sppinet that uses U32... thats why I'm asking...

Comment: @Tiago: You realize that C has the `typedef` keyword that lets you make type aliases?

Comment: Note that the types in `<cstdint>` are in namespace `std`.

Comment: I like style of u32/u64... , is there an off-shelf header file that defined these types ? many thank!!!

Answer (score 2):

While cstdint might be a solution, it's not universal -- MSVC versions before 2010 didn't ship with that one. If writing for multiple platforms you'll need to supply the standard types yourself if MSVC < 2010 is detected. Or use the [boost one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/integer/cstdint.htm) if you use boost.

Answer (score 2):

U32 is an idiomatic shortcut for an unsigned int. Its common definition is:

```
typedef unsigned int U32;
```

But the main reason for its use is to be able to control the actual definition manually. Hope this helps.

Comment: `unsigned int` is not guaranteed to be 32 bits so such a typedef is just really bad.

Comment: yup, throw a static_assert in there :)