# Converting c++ struct to c# and using it?

Tags: c#, c++, struct

I have a c++ struct as follow:

```
struct Vehicle
{
 u32 something;
 Info *info;
 u8 something2[ 0x14 ];
 Vector3f location;
 Template* data;
};

struct Info
{
 u32 speed;
 std::string name;
 BuffCollection** buffCollection;
 void* sectionPtr;
};

struct Template
{
 u32 templateID;
};
```

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218220/c-u32-type-header), I figured out the meaning of the u32, u8, and so on, or so I think I did.

Then I tried to make my own C# struct out of it:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Vehicle
{
    public uint Something;
    public Info Info;
    public byte Something2;
    public Vector3f Location;
    public Template Data;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Info
{
    public uint Speed;
    public string Name;
    public byte[] BuffCollection;
    public IntPtr SectionPointer;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Template
{
    public uint TemplateId;
}

public struct Vector3f
{
    public float X, Y, Z;
    public Vector3f(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to read the Vehicle:

```
[DllImport("Core.dll")]
static extern Vehicle GetVehicle();

static void Main() 
{
    var vehicle = GetVehicle();
    Console.WriteLine(vehicle.Info.Name);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible
```

From the search I did on it, it lead me to believe that my structure conversion is wrong.

- **What is wrong with my converted structures?**

Comment: Is my question wrong? I see a vote to close without any information why... Is it because at the bottom I have 3 points? if so I can remove the other 2 and make them a new question.

Comment: What's the C++ signature of the function?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Vehicle* GetVehicle();` not sure if this is what you're looking for but that's all I know besides the structures as I don't have access to the DLL source code.

Comment: Take note of `something2` within `Vehicle`, since it's an array.

Comment: @Caramiriel so it should be a `byte[]`?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure (since I don't use interop). It's just something I noticed. Edit to comment below: yes, any list/array typed c field should match a field of the same type in c# (array as well).

Comment: @Caramiriel thanks I will give it a try, would a `u32 driver[29];` be any different than `uint Driver` as well? Its unrelated to the structs above but also seen on another I will soon have to work with.

Comment: You say that the C++ function returns a `Vehicle*`, but in C# you have declared it as returning `Vehicle`. Are you sure this is what you intended?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I am not a c++ person and honestly I don't know what the * means in fact I am reading about it now after u mentioned they are different.

Comment: `Vehicle*` is a pointer to a `Vehicle`. You can declare the return type as `Vehicle*` in C# as well, I believe (provided that you are in an `unsafe` type and you have set your project settings to allow compilation of unsafe code - that's when C# allows you to use pointers).

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I see, I will try that thanks. About the structures are they right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding structures:

1. `Vehicle.Info` is a pointer, so you need to declare it as `IntPtr Info`, and then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure / Marshal.StructureToPtr` to read/write its value in managed code;
2. `Vehicle.something2` is a byte array, not a byte, so you need to declare it this way:

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=20)]
   byte[] something2=new byte[20];
3. `Vehicle.Data` - see #1, the same problem
4. `Info.Name` - .NET does not provide marshalling for std::string, so you will either need to write your own marshaler (see this: [Custom Marshaler for PInvoke with std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099611/custom-marshaler-for-pinvoke-with-stdstring)) or change the type to something like char* in your c++ library.
5. `Info.BuffCollection` should also be an IntPtr or BuffCollection[] (depending on what the BuffCollection type is about - it's not provided in your question)

Regarding the signature and invocation of `GetVehicle();` method:

it is likely that the method returns the pointer to the structure, not the structure itself (just speculating, please double check). If so, you need to declare it as

```
static extern IntPtr GetVehicle();
```

and then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to convert it to your structure like this:

```
var vehiclePtr=GetVehicle();
var vehicle = (Vehicle)Marshal.PtrToStructure(vehiclePtr, typeof(Vehicle));
```

Comment: Hi Denis, thanks for the detailed answer, could you post an example of how I would use Marshal.PtrToStructure on the function?

Comment: Sure, added the example to my response

Comment: Would it be possible to use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] public Info Info;` instead of `IntPtr Data`?

Comment: I don't think so. UnmanagedType.Struct indicates that the variable contains the structure, but in your case it is a pointer to the structure (Info *info). You may try to use UnmanagedType.LPStruct, but I've never tried it. Marshal.PtrToStructure is more "conventional" way IMHO